# How to create multiselect dropdownlist with textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to create multiselect dropdownlist with text box. In my dropdownlist I have "other" option when I click "[other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDNvh.png)" option then I have to display text box inside the dropdownlist to Enter custom value. and also I facing the problem while second time click my dropdownlist was not opened.

This is my CSHTML code:

```
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TrainingToolValue, new MultiSelectList(Model.TrainingTool, "TrainingToolID", "ToolName"), new { @id = "TrainingToolId", @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
```

This is my Script code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TrainingToolId").multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
    });
}); </script>
```

Is there any possiblities to add text box inside the dropdownlist